# How to change background color from transparent to black gradually on window scroll

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, scrollview, background-color

I'm trying to achieve an effect similar to that in the video below but I did not find anything after several searches:

https://d.pr/oKFD

I have a simple html like this:

```
<div class="item">
<a class="my-img-url-class" href="some-url"><img src="my-url/my-img.jpg" class="img-class"></a>
</div>
```

Everything I did before was to make it work onlly the *fade in* effect using the code below but this is not what I need:

```
var divs = $('.item');
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   divs.css({ 'opacity' : (1 - st/350) });
});
```

I need a background color over a div/image to be changed from transparent to black gradually on window scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need jquery to achieve this. Here is what you should write:

```
function myScroll() {
  var scrolled = document.documentElement.scrollTop; // Firefox & IE
  var SCROLLED = document.body.scrollTop // Chrome, Safari & Opera
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.item')
  var opac = 1 - 360 / scrolled;
  var OPAC = 1 - 360 / SCROLLED;
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].style.opacity = opac;
    divs[i].style.opacity = OPAC;
  }
}
document.addEventListener("scroll", myScroll);
```

Comment: Thanks @Wais but I guess is something wrong with your code since inspecting element the item div opacity remains unchanged to 1 even I scroll or not: `<div class="item" style="opacity: 1;">`

Comment: I tried it on chrome. It works well. If you encounter any issues just check that the script is placed as the last element in the `<body>` tag, not in the `<head>` tag.

Comment: Sorry, I need a dark overlay not opacity from 0 to 1.